# Nodejs- Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm currently designing a oauth login system and I've encountered the following problem. I'm trying to redirect users back to the homepage once they have been logged in and session data has been set, but the `res.redirect('/')` throws `NodeError: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. I cannot seem to get it to work. Below is the code which is causing the fault:

```js
      app.post(
    "/auth/openid/return",
    passport.authenticate("azuread-openidconnect", {
      failureRedirect: "/login"
    }),
    function(req, res) {
      let userProperties = req.user;
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          if (err) next(err);
          let dbo = db.db("Lektier");
          let query = {
            oid: req.user.oid
          };
          dbo.collection("users").findOne(query, function(err, result) {
            db.close();
            if (result) {
              let type = result.type;
              resolve(type);
            }
          });
        });
      }).then(type => {
        req.session.regenerate(function() {
          req.session.user = userProperties.upn;
          if (type == "teacher") {
            req.session.teacheruser = userProperties.upn;
          }
          let names = userProperties.displayName.toString().split(" ");
          req.session.FirstName = names[0];
          req.session.LastName = names[1];
          res.redirect("/");
        });
      });
    }
  );
```

Some help on the matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any other routes that match `POST /auth/openid/return`? It could be intercepted by another middleware

Comment: There is a `GET /auth/openid/return`, but the code within is identical as the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you see a message like this `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, it means that the logic of your endpoint tried to send a response to the client and failed, because *it actually already responded*. `res.redirect()` of express actually sends some 3xx http status to the client and if you are saying that this method throws the error you're facing, something before it already sent a response.

I didn't find anything that could respond in the snippet you provided (besides the very res.redirect()), so I suggest you to look into your middleware. For example into passport authentication, since it is mentioned here.